# Hierarchical directory structure in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Is there any function in X-Query or Node-JS client API to get the list of directories or hierarchical view of files in Marklogic 9?

Comment: You can use the cts:uris() function in XQuery - but can you clarify what is the final output that you desire?

Comment: I am trying to design front end to look like folder hierarchical structure, So if the get the list of directories or directory structure then i can pass those and create that structure in front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories in MarkLogic are just conventions reflected by document URIs.

No resource corresponding to a directory exists in the database (with the exception of an edge case for WebDav).

As Tamas hints in his comment, you can write an XQuery or JavaScript function to

- read URIs from the URI lexicon
- sort
- tokenize the URIs on the / into URI steps
- group on the steps to build the hierarchy

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

There's a recipe on developer.marklogic.com that should help: http://developer.marklogic.com/recipe/list-directory-count

```
declare function local:map-uris($uris as xs:string*)
{
  let $map := map:map()
  let $_ := 
    for $uri in $uris
    let $toks := fn:tokenize($uri, "/")
    for $t at $i in fn:subsequence($toks, 1, fn:count($toks) - 1)
    let $key := fn:string-join($toks[1 to $i], "/") || "/"
    let $count := (map:get($map, $key), 0)[1]
    return map:put($map, $key, ($count + 1) )
  return $map
};

local:map-uris(cts:uris())
```